# Select the first log in Time using from Table using SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a table of employees that describe his last and first name, his Card ID and times he log in to an enterprise. I want to select the first time he logs in.

thise is a example of the table

[thise is a example of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Po00h.png)

and this is the result that I want
[this is the result that I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjyUF.png)

Comment: you should have given data instead of images.Secondly your table is very badly design.Instead of LastName,FirstName it should be Empid because there will be lot of record and your query will require aggregate or partition function.you should try like row_number()over partition by(last_name,firt_name,field_time)

Comment: Is the card ID unique for each login attempt?

Comment: the card id is unique for each employee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could group by the last name, first name and truncated date and return the minimal date per group. In modern SQL Server versions this truncation is pretty simple - you just cast the `field_time` to a `date`:

```
SELECT   last_name,
         first_name,
         CAST(field_time AS DATE) AS log_day,
         MIN(field_time) AS first_log
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY last_name, first_name, CAST(field_time AS DATE)
```

Comment: why i can't select ID ?

Comment: you can add id in the first line and with group by function because id is not like describet in the picture but the id is unique for each employee like example: fo r Employee A. ID is 1 and for B. is 2.          Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I maintain table design is bad.

try this,

```
insert into @t values(1, 'A.','A.','01.01.2016 10:20:00')
     ,(2,'A.','A.','01.01.2016 12:22:00')
     ,(3,'A.','A.','03.01.2016 08:50:00')
     ,(4,'B.','B.','01.01.2016 15:08:00')

;WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY lastname
            ,firstname
            ,cast(feildtime AS DATE) ORDER BY feildtime
            ) rn
    FROM @t
    )
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: if there is any unique column like CARd_ID then fine,you can only use CARD_ID in partition like row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY Card_ID            ,cast(feildtime AS DATE) ORDER BY feildtime ) rn

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've made a copy of this table for my testing as per below;

```
CREATE TABLE DateTest
(
ID int
,LAST_NAME varchar(10)
,FIRST_NAME varchar(10)
,FIELD_TIME datetime
)
```

Inserted your data EDIT: updated the ID field on second row as advised in comments;

```
INSERT INTO DateTest (ID, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, FIELD_TIME)
VALUES
(1, 'A.', 'A.', '2016-01-01 10:20:00')
,(1, 'A.', 'A.', '2016-01-01 12:22:00')
,(3, 'A.', 'A.', '2016-01-03 08:50:00')
,(4, 'B.', 'B.', '2016-01-01 15:08:00')
```

What you're trying to do requires you to group by the date, you can do that with something like the query below;

```
SELECT 
ID
,LAST_NAME
,FIRST_NAME
,CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(date,FIELD_TIME)) LOG_DATE
,MIN(FIELD_TIME) LOG_IN
FROM DateTest
GROUP BY
ID
,LAST_NAME
,FIRST_NAME
,CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(date,FIELD_TIME))
```

I would very much advise on including an Employee_ID column or similar. You'll run into issues if you get two employees with the same names, you'll have no way of differentiating.

Comment: ID rerpresent  Employee_ID that means that for A ID=1 and fro B ID=2

Comment: In the data originally supplied you've got 4 rows of data with 4 unique employee ID's. Assuming the second line should be employee ID 1 then you'd want to remove the MIN function from the ID field in my final query so that it just selects the ID field, you'll then want to add ID to the group by.

Comment: No worries, I've updated the code above if you need it for reference. In your example of the output data you also don't have the ID field included, I'd highly recommend you include this field, it's the field that you want to be using to identify employees.

Comment: Thanks you for your help